# Size of Data transfer Via TLS (Transfer Layer Security)

Tags: ssl

What amount of data can be transferred over a T.L.S. (Transfer Layer Security) protocol?

Answer (score 2):

Any amount you like. TCP is a byte stream protocol and so is TLS. Under the hood, they both packetize, but you can't control that, or even see it in most cases.